# Filehelpers - Export with double quotes around each field EXCEPT when field is blank/null

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I may have missed the answer when searching but I have a file that needs all fields double quoted EXCEPT when a field is blank, missing or null then only the comma will be entered.

I'm using `[FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)]` with the sample following output:

```
"Mary","Smith","555-555-5555","","1234","","3141 Pi Cr."
```

But I need the output to actually look like this:

```
"Mary","Smith","555-555-5555",,"1234",,"3141 Pi Cr."
```

Any suggestions using Filehelpers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [`INotifyWrite`](http://www.filehelpers.net/example/EventsAndNotification/INotifyWrite/) event to modify the output before writing to the file.

For instance

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
class Product : INotifyWrite // <-- implement events
{
    [FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)]
    public string Name;
    [FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)]
    public string Description;
    [FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)]
    public string Size;

    public void BeforeWrite(BeforeWriteEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public void AfterWrite(AfterWriteEventArgs e)
    {
        // replace any occurrences of ,"", with ,,
        e.RecordLine = e.RecordLine.Replace(",\"\",", ",,");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks shamp00. That's exactly what I ended up doing after finding nothing more "native" that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to solve the issue:

```
[FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForWrite)]
```

Comment: Why? Where would this be more appropriate than the approach taken in the accepted answer (which uses `AlwaysQuoted`)?